# MySQL Calculating Average of Aliased Count Columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm attempting to calculate the average of excused and unexcused applications for a project I'm working on.

This is the current query I have:

```
SELECT Count(unexcused) as Unexcused, Count(Points_Assigned) as Excused,
COUNT(Agent_ID) as numAgents
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT Entry_ID, Points_Assigned FROM Table2
    WHERE Points_Assigned = 0
) AS T2 USING(Entry_ID)
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT Entry_ID, Points_Assigned as unexcused FROM Table2
    WHERE Points_Assigned > 0
) AS T3 USING(Entry_ID)
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT Employee_ID as Agent_ID FROM Table3
    WHERE Team = 1
) AS T4 USING(Agent_ID)
```

Which correctly results in:

```
Unexcused |  Excused  |  numAgents
    12    |    14     |     69
```

I want to use the numAgents to calculate the average of excused and unexcused absences on average per agent.

What is the best solution to do this in one query using the data I already have?

I've tried doing `(Unexcused / numAgents) AS AverageUnexcused` but am getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error are you getting? You could try

```
    (Count(unexcused)/COUNT(Agent_ID)) AS AverageUnexcused.
```

Comment: Aha, it was the double count and the nesting of the parenthesis in the proper order that fixed it, thanks so much!